# Splitting Rows into Columns - Dates to Days with matching Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have the following data:

| PersonID | Event | Date | Name | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Event A | 31/12/1900 | John | Pending |
| 1 | Event A | 01/01/1901 | John | Pending |
| 2 | Event B | 31/12/1900 | Sarah | Pending |
| 2 | Event B | 01/01/1901 | Sarah | Complete |

I would like to SELECT this data based on date and other parameters and display the following with each date being matched to its individual day and displaying the matching status, I've just started with Monday/Tuesday to attempt this, but will expand to Monday - Friday.

| PersonID | Event | Name | Monday | Tuesday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Event A | John | Pending | Pending |
| 2 | Event B | Sarah | Pending | Complete |

I've written the following, trying to proof of concept this on Monday/Tuesday columns. I admit, this is a simplified version there are LEFT JOIN's to add in the peoples name from a details table, but I don't believe that should affect why this isn't working for me. (?!)

```
SELECT
       [PersonID]
      ,[event]
      ,[name]
      ,[status] AS Monday
      ,NULL AS Tuesday
 
  FROM [People]

  WHERE cast([eventdate] as date) = '1900-12-31'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
       [PersonID]
      ,[event]
      ,[name]
      ,NULL AS Monday
      ,[status] AS Tuesday
 
  FROM [People]

  WHERE cast([eventdate] as date)  = '1901-01-01'
```

Instead this is showing the following:

| PersonID | Event | Name | Monday | Tuesday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Event A | John | Pending | NULL |
| 1 | Event A | John | NULL | Pending |
| 2 | Event B | Sarah | Pending | NULL |
| 2 | Event B | Sarah | NULL | Complete |

I guess I need a little nudge in the right direction on how I might achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `MAX`to pivot your table

> ```
> SELECT
> [PersonID],[Name], [Event],
> MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW,[Date]) = 2 then [Status] ELSe '' ENd) [Monday],
> MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW,[Date]) = 3 then [Status] ELSE '' ENd) [Tuesday],
> MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW,[Date]) = 4 then [Status] ELSE '' ENd) [Wednesday],
> MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW,[Date]) = 5 then [Status] ELSE '' ENd) [Thursday],
> MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW,[Date]) = 6 then [Status] ELSE '' ENd) [Friday]
> FROM tab1
> GROUP BY
> [PersonID],[Name], [Event]
> ```
>
> ```
> PersonID | Name  | Event   | Monday  | Tuesday  | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday
> -------: | :---- | :------ | :------ | :------- | :-------- | :------- | :-----
>        1 | John  | Event A | Pending | Pending  |           |          |       
>        2 | Sarah | Event B | Pending | Complete |           |          |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=338fee2e2ceafdc7cb9c960cb70a8054)*